# jasny bootstrap extension not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

i was using bootstrap earlier. Now i required file-upload feature so was trying to give jasny a try. I downloaded the extension but it is not working?

the files in my include files are (apart from jquery.js):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jasny-bootstrap/js/jasny-bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jasny-bootstrap/css/jasny-bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css">
<link href ="jasny-bootstrap/css/jasny-bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
```

The bootstrap features are all working normally. But i am not able to use this extension. Am i including it wrong.?

I am not using the complete bootstrap including all jasny extensions because it is breaking some of my previous bootstrap features.

Answer (score 0):

Have you auto-formatted your code? Because it sometimes forces the filename in the input text to drop a line and thus not making it visible but in fact it actually works fine when you try it. Just put it back on the same line then.

If not, try making sure all the paths to your css/js are correct.

Can you describe what you see?